# Add comma after volume when no issue number biblatex

Tags: bibliography, biblatex

For the bibliography of my thesis I want to add a comma after the volume number when a journal article has no issue number present.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=nejm, sorting=none, natbib=true, isbn=false, url=false, doi=true, eprint = false, giveninits]{biblatex}

% remove pp
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

% No dot before number of articles
\xpatchbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
 }{%
}{}{}

% Number of articles in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}\addcomma}

% Comma before date; date not in parentheses
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
 \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% 
\iffieldundef{issue}
  {\usebibmacro{date}}
  {\printfield{issue}%
   \setunit*{\addspace}%
   \usebibmacro{date}}% 
\newunit}

% comma after journal 
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
 \usebibmacro{journal}%
 \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
 \iffieldundef{series}
 {}
{\newunit
 \printfield{series}%
 \setunit{\addspace}}%
\usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
 \setunit{\addspace}%
\usebibmacro{issue+date}%
 \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
\usebibmacro{issue}%
\newunit}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@article{einstein,
 author = {Albert Einstein},
 title = {On the electrodynamics of moving bodies},
 journal = {Annalen der Physik},
 volume = {322},
 number = {10},
 pages = {891--921},
 year = {1905},
 DOI = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004}
}
@article{test,
 author = {Example, Author},
 journal = {Journal},
 pages = {2},
 title = {{Test paper}},
 volume = {5},
 year = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{sample.bib} 

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Currently the code output looks like this:
[image]

I have attempted to adapt the code from this question asking about changing separator when no volume number is present  (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199301/change-separator-for-articles-in-journals-without-volume-number-biblatex), for issue number:

```
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{%
 \ifentrytype{article}{%
  \iffieldundef{number}
  {\addcomma\space}}
  {\space}}
```

However this removes the space and comma from between the year and page range, when there is an issue number present, not what I intended at all. Please can someone help to show me where I'm going wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with this issue by inserting the code below in `\DeclareBibliographyDriver`.

```latex
\iffieldundef{number}
    {\addcomma\space}
    {\printfield{number}\addcomma\space}
```

Here's my code chunk.

```latex
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
    \printnames{author}%
    \printfield{year}%  
    \printfield{title}%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
%   \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \iffieldundef{number}
    {\addcomma\space}
    {\printfield{number}\adddot\space}%
    \iffieldundef{pages}
    {}
    {\printfield{pages}\adddot}%
```

Though the reference format could be different, you may get the main idea that I try to deliver here.